# My ps4 won’t charge or connect controllers. It’s stuck at “press the PlayStation button to start”

Tags: ps4, controllers

I recently unpacked my ps4 after moving and when trying to start it it won’t charge or connect controllers. We even bought a new controller.

Comment: Not even charging? Have you tried the other USB port? Does it charge on a different source? Basically check if the controller is dead or if the cable is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you bought a new controller and it still doesn't connect there are 2 options: the problem is either the cable or something in the ps4 is broken.

Try to test the cable on something else or try to connect your controller with another cable.

If you realize the problem is not the cable then it's probably the console itself, and at this point you can't do much else than contact a Sony center to get it repaired.